# Display a captcha in a form, some of the times only

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a blog coded in sf1.4; and I use recaptcha in the form
for comments. Some users have complained about the captcha, but I
don't want to remove it completely.

Is it possible to, for instance, remove the captcha, but turn it on
for a few minutes after the user has posted a comment ?

That way, it doesn't discourage occasional users from commenting, and
prevents someone from spamming automatically the website.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like enable it in a session after a user has made some number of posts which can be random as well like after 2-4 posts maybe? Even better display it after every say `1 + rand(5)` posts?
Tracking the number of posts made in a session should not be difficult - you just need to keep a counter per user session.